# How get token from headers to test my controller by mocking the service class

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit.net

```
public class AdditionDto
{
    public int HttpCode {get; set:}
    public string UserName {get; set:}
    public int Total {get; set:}
}

public interface IAddtionService
{
    AdditionDto AddingTwoNumbers(int input1, int input2, string userName);
}

public class AdditionService : IAdditionService
{
    public AdditionDto AddingTwoNumbers(int input1, int input2, string userName)
    {
        AdditionDto addDto = new AdditionDto()
        {
             httpCode = 200,
             UserName = userName,
             Total = input1 + input2
        }
        return addDto;
    }
}
```

With a controller like this:

```
public class AdditionController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAddtionService _additionService;
    public AdditionController(IAddtionService additionService)
    {
         _additionService = additionService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [Route("AddtionOfTwoNumbers")]
    public IActionResult AddTwoNumbers(int input1, int input2)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            var tokenbearer = token.Split(' ');
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var decodedtoken = handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenbearer[1]);
            string user = decodedtoken.Claims.Where(x => x.Type ==         "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            var usr = user.Split(":");
            string userName = usr[2].Trim();

            var result = _additionService.AddingTwoNumbers(input1, input2,userName);

            if (result.Httpcode == 200)
                return Ok(result);
            else
                 return StatusCode(500, result);
         }
         else
            return BadRequest();
      }
}
```

When i am trying to conduct xunit test on this api I am getting null at header level.
also I need to mock service method that is also not happening. mostly it is showing null exception even I have passed token in the headers also then I am facing mocking issue at the service method level. could you please help me to mock my service method to test that api through xunit framework....